# Replace removes punctuation?

Tags: ruby, string, replace

My task is to replace all instances of `'you'`, `'u'`, and `'youuuu'` (with numbers of `'u'`) in a string with `'your sister'`.

Here's my code:

```
def autocorrect(input)
  words = input.split()
  words.each do |word|
    if word == 'u' || word == 'you'
      word.replace 'your sister'
    elsif word.include? 'you'
      word.replace 'your sister'
    end
  end
  words = words.join(' ')
  words
end
```

My code replaces the word correctly, but it also removes punctuation. I get this:

```
autocorrect("I miss you!")
# => "I miss your sister"
```

There is no exclamation point in the output. Does anybody know why this happens?

Comment: What is the desired return value for the string "uyou youuuu u".

Comment: I'm realizing my code would not work for all tests. Desired output for that would be "uyou your sister your sister", the test is asking to replace 'you' but not when its a part of another word

Comment: This is how I just passed the tests:

Comment: def autocorrect(input)
  input.gsub(/\b(you+|u)\b/i, 'your sister')
end

Comment: looking between word boundaries for 'you' and any number of 'u' attached to it....much shorter than what i had written, regex is powerful tool....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based in part on a comment on the question, I have assumed the substring to be replaced cannot be immediately preceded or followed by a letter.

```
r = /
    (?<!\p{alpha}) # do not match a letter (negative lookbehind)
    (?:            # begin non-capture group
      you+         # match 'yo' followed by one of more 'u's
      |            # or
      u            # match 'u'
    )              # close non-capture group
    (?!\p{alpha})  # do not match a letter (negative lookahead)
    /x             # free-spacing regex definition mode

"uyou you youuuuuu &you% u ug".gsub(r, "your sister")
  #=> "uyou your sister your sister &your sister% your sister ug"
```

This regular expression is conventionally written

```
/(?<!\p{alpha})(?:you+|u)(?!\p{alpha})/
```

Answer (score 2):

When you split a string with whitespace in ruby, it takes the punctuation with it.

Try splitting a sentence like "I like candy!" and inspecting the last element. You'll notice it's the word "candy!" exclamation point and all.

Answer (score 1):

I think instead using replace, you could use gsub, replacing the `you`, with your sister, this way it keeps the exclamation mark.

Because `replace` would replace the whole string that's being passed, e.g:

```
p 'you!'.replace('your sister')     # => "your sister"
p 'you!'.gsub(/you/, 'your sister') # => "your sister!"
```

So you could try with:

```
def autocorrect(input)
  words = input.split()
  words.each do |word|
    if word == 'u' || word == 'you'
      word.replace 'your sister'
    elsif word.include? 'you'
      word.gsub!(/you/, 'your sister') 
    end
  end
  words = words.join(' ')
  words
end

p autocorrect("I miss you!")
# => "I miss your sister!"
```

Note just using gsub on your input would give you the expected output.